# smarty grammar error cannot use symbol []

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

This line:

```
{$data["bank_data"]["Arrangement"]["id"]}
```

returns the following error:

> PHP (5.3.9) ERROR (E_USER_ERROR):
>   File: Smarty.class.php
>   Line: 1092
>   Type: Smarty error: [in tke-g-admin_scopeofwork.tpl line 10]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: $data["bank_data"]["Arrangement"]["id"] (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 446)

This line:

```
{$data.bank_data.Arrangement.id}
```

does not return error. It works correctly.

So, why the first section is wrong? How to use `[]` to access array.

Comment: eh? If `Smarty` tells you to use dot `.` notation, you just have to follow it :s, any particular reason of avoiding `.` notation?

Comment: how to solve  $a["a  b"]  which contain blank problem?

Comment: don't use space as array key? :D, seriously though: Try `{$a[a b]}`

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the error you posted, you're using Smarty2. [The Docs](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl) give you two options for accessing arrays:

```
{* for string indexes *}
{$some.array.value}
{* for numeric indexes *}
{$some[0][1]}
```

you can use a variable to provide an index like so

```
{assign var="key" value="array"}
{$some.$key.value} == {$some.array.value}
```

using that "trick", you can also access string indexes containing "special characters" such as `.`, `[]` or .

---

Smarty3 is a bit more flexible in that way:

```
{$some.{"hello world"}.array["array"]['foo']}
```

oddly enough `{$foo[bar]}` is not parsed properly (in Smarty 3.1.10). Threw that on the todo list, though.